# Complete SQLite newbie - how to install SQLCipher for UWP app

Tags: sqlite, uwp, sqlcipher

I am working on a UWP app where we need to use SQLCipher but I have no idea how to install it and cannot find a single up to date guide or reference anywhere, inlcuding on Zetetec's site or at the GitHub repository page.
Unfortunately I have never used SQLite before so I am really wanting to know, from scratch please, what I need to do to enable SQLCipher in my UWP app.

For example, do I have to do a local build of SQLite first (with nmake?) or can I use the existing SQLite NuGet packages (SQLite.UWP.Native)  then just install one of the ericsink packages such as SQLitePCLRaw.bundle._sqlCipher?

Hoping someone can help because I'm wandering lost and lonely here :-(

Comment: https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2015/12/01/sqlcipher-for-windows-uap/

Comment: Thanks @Shawn - I saw that but it's well out of date (2015) in that there is no "SQLCipher for Universal Window App Platform" package anymore. the only one I can see that looks to be anything to do with  Zetetec is SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_zetetic but that only references the official SQLCipher build - so I cannot see where in NuGet to get the SQLCipher package from.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved - I got an official trial of SQLCipher and after installation and setup according to the PDF they include in the ZIP package all is working well.